# If I have a $45$ bit ternary number, where $x$ bits must be $0$, $y$ bits must be $1$, and $z$bits must be $2$...

Tags: discrete-mathematics, binomial-coefficients

... How, knowing a specific $x$, $y$, and $z$, can I find how many different combinations of $0$,$1$,and $2$ can I have?

I have a specific problem. $15$ bits must be zero, $20$ must be one, and $10$ must be $2$. But I want to know HOW to solve this problem, so a general answer would be best, using these numbers as an example.

I know I have to use binomial coefficients to solve the question, but don't know just how to begin, considering that it's a ternary sequence.

So, to restate the question:

If I have a $45$ bit ternary sequence with a set $x$ number of $0s$,  a set $y$ number of $1s$, and a set $z$ number of $2s$, how many combinations can I have?

Comment: Figure out how many ways there are to place the 0s. For each way to place the 0s figure out how many ways there are to place the 1s. Given a selection of 0s and 1s there is only one way to place the 2s.

Answer (score 1):

Given $x,y$, and $z$, there are $\binom{x+y+z}x$ ways to choose $x$ positions for the zeroes. The ones can fill any $y$ of the remaining $y+z$ positions, so once the zeroes have been placed, there are $\binom{y+z}y$ ways to place the ones. The twos are then forced to occupy the remaining $z$ positions, so the final answer is

$$\binom{x+y+z}x\binom{y+z}y$$

possible $(x+y+z)$-bit ternary strings with $x$ zeroes, $y$ ones, and $z$ twos. This can also be written as the [multinomial coefficient](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Multinomial_theorem#Multinomial_coefficients)

$$\binom{x+y+z}{x,\,y,\,z}\;.$$